# How to specify a condition in an unnest cross join BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with multiple nestings. The use case looks like the following:

{"name":"1","line_items":[{"name":"shirt","quantity":"1","properties":[{"name":"title","value":"big"}],{"name":"sweater","quantity":"1","properties":[{"name":"title","value":"small"},
{"name":"parent_id","value":"123"}]]}

In this example, there is obviously multiple line items per order (any amount). There is also multiple properties per line item, and some line items have less properties than others.

So the parent_id should be NULL when the property does not exist for the line item, in this case parent_id.

I could do something like this:

```
SELECT 
orders.name AS order, 
line_items.name AS product, 
properties.value AS parent_id
FROM 
orders, 
UNNEST(line_items) oli,
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(properties) properties
WHERE
properties.name = 'parent_id'
```

However, this removes the NULLs, and negates the point of the left join. The current method of Left joining to an unnested properties object duplicates line items if I don't include the filter, and I am attempting to have an output that is flat and on the line item level, i.e.

[image]

How can I reference a property by name here, retain NULLs, and keep the output at a line item level?

Further context, if this were normalized, it would simply be

```
SELECT 
orders.name AS order, 
line_items.name AS product, 
properties.value AS parent_id
FROM 
orders, 
JOIN line_items oli
ON orders.id = oli.order_id
LEFT JOIN properties
oli.id = properties.line_item_id
AND properties.name = 'parent_id'
```

The IDs being necessary for the normalized version, and not for the de-normalized version. With the normalized version, I can retain the NULL and avoid duplication by specifying the filter condition for properties in the join, but I can't seem to do the same in a nested table.

Edit: Looks like a subquery in the select clause is an option:

```
SELECT 
orders.name AS order, 
line_items.name AS product, 
(SELECT properties.value FROM UNNEST(oli.properties) props WHERE props.name = 'parent_id') AS parent_id
FROM 
orders, 
UNNEST(line_items) oli
```

Any better way?

Comment: it is still not clear what is exactly the input data and what is expected output. can you provide clear example please - check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)